Android Compose Talkback FocusRequester.RequestFocus only triggers once
Original Question: Is there an equivalent to View.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null) for Composables in Android Compose?
Since typing this question with no response, the next best thing I'm trying is to use a Modifier.focusRequester and requesting focus. But in my scenario it only works once.
@Composeable
fun myComposable(param: LocalDateTime, onClickFunc : () -> Unit, ...other parameters) {
    val focusRequester = remember {FocusRequester()}
  
 IconButton(modifier.semantics(...).clickable(onClickLabel="labelHere"
 { 
   onClickFunc() //This function will trigger recomposition of this entire composable by changing whatever is sent to param LocalDateTime type
   focusRequester.requestFocus
 }  
 Text(modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester).focusable,      
 ...)
}

By clicking on the icon button, the onClickFunc will trigger the function passed into the composable parameters; this function changes the state variable value in the parent composable which is sent as the param LocalDateTime. I then try to request Focus onto the Text after the click; it works once, but unfortunately only once. Subsequent double taps with talkback navigation do not do this request focus.
Any steps I can take so that request focus can trigger per icon button click?

Have you tried requesting focus with side effect?
 SideEffect {
  focusRequester.requestFocus()
 }

